# request.POST does not return multiple fields values in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I started using Django to create a simple webapp.

I am using multipleselect to have a dropdown that allows multiple selection.

I tried almost all solutions found here but none of them seem to work for me.

I am using python 3.5

HTML:

```
<form action="datareturn.html" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="probs_location" multiple="multiple" name="probs_locations[]">
                {% for probs_location in probs_locations %}
              <option value="{{ probs_location }}">{{ probs_location }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
    </select>
    ...........#Other input fields

</form>

<script>
$('#probs_location').multiselect({
  enableClickableOptGroups: true
});
</script>
```

PYTHON-DJANGO:

```
def datareturn(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        print(request.POST)
        print(request.POST.getlist('probs_locations[]'))
    return HttpResponse("Success")
```

- `request.POST` returns all other fields except for multiple select
  fields.
- `request.POST.getlist('probs_locations[]')` returns a empty list.

Comment: Hi! The code seems correct. It might be the case that `request.POST.getlist('probs_locations[]')` is in fact empty. Have you tried with non-empty parameters?

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in `select` tag, multiple is an argument you simply pass like below:

```
<select id="probs_location" name="probs_locations[]" multiple>
```

That's probably why it's not recognized. Besides `probs_locations[]` looks like a terrible name, `probs_locations_list` would be a lot better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it does not solve the problem.